# Scatter chart with simple liner regression

Tags: highcharts

I have a scatter chart with multiple points. And I want to add a linear fit for those points(like simple linear regression). My question is should I calculate the regression with the formula and get the data array and populate as a line here(which is very complicated), or is there any function that I can directly use to get the linear regression line?

Comment: What type of linear regression?  Something like least squares is pretty simplistic; in fact if you were to google a bit, I'm sure you'd find lots of javascript implementations.

Comment: In Highcharts there is no function for that, you need to calculate on your own.

Comment: simple linear regression. I think I'd better use Java lib to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles upon this:

A user (not me) created a highcharts plugin that calculates various trend lines, including linear regression. It works fairly well, but the documentation is lacking a bit.

[HighCharts Regression Plugin (Linear + Non-Linear)](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression)

Answer (score 0):

Like this on the [Highcharts demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-regression) ?

Comment: In your linked example it looks like the regression line was pre-calculated.  So I guess @crystal_ss has an answer, you have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: yes like this. But my question is how should I get the data array for the regression line?